# How to deny write permission to a folder for all users in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to deny write permission to a particuler folder in C#, I have found methods which checks for permissions and for allow permissions.

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                                                 InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
```

But there is no method to check or to deny permission in C#

Tried this code, but I want to allow admin to have full access to folder.

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\New folder\New folder");
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), 
            FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, 
            PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Deny));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

Comment: That seems like a really bad idea. How would anybody (including your own process) be able to do anything with the folder?

Comment: You are aware that deny permissions trump (sorry for that word) any allow permissions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to call [Directory.SetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) using the path and your DirectorySecurity variable after you add rules.